# Splinter/selenium interprets some characters as escape sequences

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, splinter

I'm using Selenium (3.14.0), with Splinter (0.9.0), with Chrome Webdriver, with XQuartz on Mac to test my code.

When I try entering data into a form, some characters do not arrive in the `input`. Say, I do `some_text_input.type('cats')` the input receives just 'cat'.

After some investigation I found that 3 characters get a special treatment (while all the rest pass):

- 'e' becomes backspace - and erases the previous character
- 'r' becomes return
- 's' becomes space

Note that this only occurs on Mac, and works fine in CI environment.

Has anyone bumped into anything like this? Where does the escaping happen?

Comment: I don't see it on splinter/selenium `0.9.0/3.13.0` on Windows.

Comment: Using this command: `from splinter import Browser;browser = Browser(driver_name='chrome');browser.visit('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52526184/splinter-selenium-interprets-some-characters-as-escape-sequences');browser.find_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]/div/input').type('cats')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case some poor soul bumps into this, the reason this is happening is because:

> Inside Chrome, `ui::VKEY_BACK` is short-circuited and is never
>   translated to its x key code equivalent. Chrome is not respecting the
>   remote x server’s key code mappings.

As outlined in this [chromedriver bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=677) from 2014. So the culprit is the combination of chromedriver and XQuartz. As of this writing (September 2018) there hasn't been much movement on this bug (please login at chromium.org and vote on it!). My current workaround is to ensure that offending letters are not used in my tests. So far they are: e, r, s, and, 6. There may be more.

Comment: Oi, that sounds like a nightmare to have to remember and maintain tests which do not include specific letters. My first reaction is to ditch XQuartz ‍♂️

Comment: What would you recommend as a replacement on Mac OS? (my dev machine)

Comment: We're planning to ditch chromedriver in favor of Firefox

Comment: I guess it depends on what you're using XQuartz for.  Do you need to use it with chromedriver for some reason?  or can you get away with using chromedriver directly in selenium?

Comment: Basically if the tests fail in CI, I want to run them on dev machine and visually see what the browser is doing and why things are failing. So, yes, I do need it. As I mentioned in the question - on CI things work fine - there's no XQuartz there of course.

Comment: I don't know the difference between your environment and CI but I guess what I'm asking is do you utilize any features in CI that require xquartz such as X11 forwarding?  Or are you just doing 'normal' browser testing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180902/discussion-between-marcel-wilson-and-dmitry-shvedov).